# RxPy3 group_by creates "groupedobservables" but flat_map doesn't work - Reactive Python for Data Science Refactor

Tags: python, rx-py

On deciding to learn RxPy I took the free course Reactive Python for Data Science from O'Reilly

I quickly realised that the code was written for Python 3.5 and RxPy2 so I forked the original repo and decided to learn by refactoring the code for RxPy3

The original code for version 2 was:

```
from rx import Observable

items = ["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta", "Epsilon"]

Observable.from_(items) \
    .group_by(lambda s: len(s)) \
    .flat_map(lambda grp: grp.to_list()) \
    .subscribe(lambda i: print(i))
```

I've learned enough to import `from_` and `operators` and to use `.pipe to string together the operators.

So far I have got to:

```
from rx import from_, operators as ops

items = ["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta", "Epsilon"]

from_(items).pipe(
    ops.group_by(lambda s: len(s)),
    ops.flat_map(lambda grp: grp.to_list())  # Todo grp.to_list() of a groupedobservable is not working - fix it
).subscribe(lambda i: print(i))
```

The problem is that `ops.group_by` provides a set of "groupedobservables" which `ops.flat_map` code `grp.to_list()` doesn't map into grouped lists.

The original code is here: [Reactive Python for Data Science](https://github.com/thomasnield/oreilly_reactive_python_for_data)

My refactored code is forked here [Reactive Python RxPy3](https://github.com/brianlmerritt/oreilly_reactive_python_for_data) and the lesson is the code_examples file `6.4A_grouping_into_lists.py`

Comment: I guess my main problem is not knowing how to turn the higher order groupedobservable back into a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `to_list` is an operator, it should be applied to group through nested `pipe`:

```py
from rx import of, operators as ops

of("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta", "Epsilon").pipe(
    ops.group_by(lambda s: len(s)),
    ops.flat_map(lambda grp: grp.pipe(ops.to_list()))  
).subscribe(lambda i: print(i))
```

Result:

> ```
> ['Alpha', 'Gamma', 'Delta']
> ['Beta']
> ['Epsilon']
> ```

Comment: Thanks - much appreciated!